# Docker container crashes just after launch while image build on error containing source code

Tags: docker

I have created nodejs image which has only one process, when it run as container, Goes into stopped state due to error in code which kill the node Server process. Error log  created by container isgiven below.

```
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './v1' is not defined by "exports" in /usr/src/app/node_modules/uuid/package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:285:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:491:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:444:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:484:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/models/user.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/controller/user.js:1:12) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

so my question here are as below:
Can a container run normally as it has any error in source code? or is it default behavior to crash while contains error?

Comment: Please add the contents of Dockerfile in your question. It looks like node_modules are not available in docker.

Comment: i know its the error of node, but ques is why container exit while app crashes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour of container, to exit gracefully while underlying process exits.

A docker container cannot run without it's underlying process. All it's run is the underlying process. In your case, your logs stated that it exits due to an exception at following

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/controller/user.js:1:12)
```

In case you want to restart the container in case of exit, you can set `--restart` policies to setup a restart policies, in case of exit. Here is the [Restart policy documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart).